# How to run Processing applications from the terminal

Tags: java, processing

I'm currently using [Processing](http://processing.org) for a small project, however I'm not liking the text-editor that comes with it. I use vim to write all of my code. I've found where  the .pde file are and I've been editing them from vim and then I'm reopening them and running them (it takes a lot to reload the script and running it). That's why I want a solution where I can compile everything from the terminal.

On close inspection I've found the processing-java file that supposedly compiles and runs a sketch. However whatever arguments I supply it, it keeps on spitting the help page.
This is an example on how I'm running them.

(PS: I made a script that runs processing-java and added it to /usr/bin)

`processing-java --sketch=/home/george/sketchbook/testproject --output=/tmp/processing/test --force --run`

Can anyone help me please run my sketchs from the terminal?

Comment: I gave it a try too, looks like it's broken. Head over to http://code.google.com/p/processing/issues and file a bug report on it. Processing 2.0 is still in beta, so this is something they'll want to fix before releasing.

Comment: This runs flawlessly for me on MacOS 10.8 with Processing 2.0b7. What OS are you on? Can you post your script?

Comment: For the record, Processing has moved away from Google Code and towards GitHub. The current place to file a bug is at https://github.com/processing

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I managed to do it by creating a bash script called pjava and the code is as follow if anyone is having this question:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -rf /tmp/processing
mkdir /tmp/processing
/home/euler/Desktop/processing-2.0b8/processing-java --output=/tmp/processing/ --force --sketch=$1 --run
```

And the way I run it is as follow:

If I am inside a folder called `project`, I run `pjava ../project` and project.pde will get compiled and run.

Answer (score 3):

I know that this is late, but a simpler way would be to do it like this (assuming processing-java is in your path).
`processing-java --sketch=$PWD --run`
and add it to an alias:
`alias pjava='processing-java --sketch=$PWD --run`

Comment: This runs it, but where does it outputs the folder/file? Is it temporary or is it saving itself somewhere in my computer?

Comment: Add the argument: `--output=/place/to/output`

Answer (score 1):

You can also just keep the processing app open and use any editor.

When you save the changes in say VS code (I have the processing extension but don't think that does anything but syntax highlighting), it will show in the processing app and you can run it from there. Having a script is nice, but processing's visual interface is handy too.

Answer (score 0):

better way to start processing in linux using terminal is to navigate to the directory has processing-java file and then in write

**./processing**

to start the software